# React Bootstrap Typeahead - setting input styles

Tags: react-bootstrap-typeahead

This is a great component - just wondering if there's a simple way to apply css styles to the actual input element? e.g. to set the background colour via a prop

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `inputProps` to apply props directly to the input component:

```js
<Typeahead
  ...
  inputProps={{
    className: 'my-custom-classname',
    style: {
      'backgroundColor': 'red',
    }
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Perfect - can’t upvote as I don’t have the rep. Thanks